# Thread Safety and Class Method Parameters 

Tags: c#, multithreading

Take the following code:

```
 public void SomeMethodWithParameters(MutableObject mutableParameter, String stringParameter, double structParameter)
    {
       // some code
    }
```

It is my understanding that this code is not thread-safe due to the fact that mutableParameter is changeable outside of this method.

What strategies do you employ in code (other than only using immutable classes or structs as parameters) to protect against this possibility?  Should all passed objects to this method actually be deep-clones?

Comment: In C#, I think the usual meaning for "reference parameter" is a `ref` parameter.  Perhaps "parameters of reference type" would be more clear?

Comment: It's only an issue *if* mutableParameter *can* change during the method call.  If no other thread has a reference to mutableParameter, then it doesn't matter that it's changeable outside of the method, because it's not going to change...

Comment: For the sake of argument, it *is* modfiable outside of the method call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It is my understanding that this code is not thread-safe due to the fact that mutableParameter is changeable outside of this method.

To clarify: the contents of *the variable* "mutableParameter" are not going to change; that variable is going to refer to the same instance throughout its lifetime (provided you do not change it in the method). The contents of variables owned by the instance being referred to could change if some other thread that has a reference to the same object is mutating them.

> What strategies do you employ in code (other than only using immutable classes or structs as parameters) to protect against this possibility?

If possible, avoid the problem entirely. Don't read and write the same variables of the same object on multiple threads in the first place.

If you cannot avoid it, then make a suitably accessible lock object.

Define a locking protocol such that you promise to lock the object before you access any variable that could be accessed on another thread. Unlock it when you're done.

- Make sure to order your locks to prevent deadlock.
- Lock objects should be as inaccessible as possible. Private is better than internal, and internal is way, way better than public.  Never choose something like a type as a lock object; you can't control who locks it in what order, and therefore you have a deadlock potential.
- Make sure that *every* access to the variable on *every* thread follows the protocol. It does no good whatsoever to lock 99 out of 100 accesses and let the 100th in without a lock. If you cannot prevent code you do not control from accessing the resource then the resource itself needs to be rewritten to be made threadsafe.
- Measure your performance and see how often the lock is contended. If the lock is heavily contended, change your architecture to prevent contention. Only if you absolutely positively have a serious problem that you cannot make better any other way should you attempt a no-lock or low-lock solution.

Comment: understood regarding the contents vs the reference itself.

Comment: but if the class parameter you are passing into the method could be also modified from another class, how can you ensure you are locking on the same object instance (without statics)

Comment: @miguel: And now you know why it's so hard to write correct multithreaded code! You've got to design a protocol that works for the specific situation you face. How you do that is up to you.

Comment: Don't forget to document the situation and protocol! I find it very helpful to put IntelliSense compatible comments around my methods that describe how the multithreading protocol I designed works. I also recommend `readonly` and type `object` for your locking object, if possible. It will generate a compiler warning if you change it by accident. Something like `private readonly object myLock = new object();`

Comment: @Eric: Are you an expert in parallel programming? I ask this because I am not sure how much you write multi-threaded code, but you write a lot about it. So I assume you know it very well. If you do, I was wondering if it's a good idea to not deal with the current immaturity in multi-threaded programming and wait it out until something more established comes along?

Comment: @Joan: I am far from an expert; I know just enough to know how little I know! The trouble is that most people who try to write multithreaded code don't even know that much. I think if you wait for something better to come along, you could wait a long time; that said, if you have a problem that needs concurrency, parallelism or asynchrony, by all means embrace higher-level  abstractions than "thread". The Task Parallel Library for example is good at abstracting away thread management issues.

Comment: @Eric: Are you aware of established, effective patterns for properly ordering locks?  "Order your locks" was something we were taught in school, yet even 8 years out of school I have yet to see anything but a manually munged locking technique.  Fortunately(?), the vast majority of code that I've worked with hasn't been multi-threaded with lower-level abstractions like mutexes, either.

Comment: @Greg: I'm not aware of any such thing. Multi-threading with locks where threads can be waiting on each other inherently requires the programmer to have global knowledge of the possible lock states of the entire system; that's what makes it so hard. I'm not very good at it, frankly. I tend to leave this stuff to experts.

Comment: @Thanks Eric. I will follow your advice. But do you think using stuff like `BrackgroundWorker` is also higher level abstraction?